# Is it possible to write an automatic garbage collector for one language in another language?

Tags: python, c, garbage-collection, cpython

Taking the instance of C programming language which doesn't have a automatic garbage collector. I have come across other garbage collectors for C, such as the Boehm-Demers-Weiser garbage collector and other implementations. But, all of them are in the same language (C) or CPP.
Python has an API for C which can be used to create PyObjects in the heap which also come with a reference counter. Is it possible use Python to create a garbage collector for C? Does creating objects using the CPython API, also creates objects in the embedded interpreter? Can it be used in any way to create an automatic garbage collector for C?

Please pardon me if there is anything wrong above. I'm new to this.

Comment: What's your actual use case on this? Can you be specific rather than asking a broad opinion?

Comment: C in itself doesn't have an inbuilt garbage collector. We can always use external libraries/modules to provide that feature, by using memory allocation functions (from those libraries). My use case would be, to implement a garbage collector for C using Python language. It would be something like, creating objects using the CPython API from C and then managing memory (heap) (garbage collection) for C in Python. @SivasubramaniamArunachalam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C and Python are two very different languages. C is a *compiled* language, while Python is *interpreted*.

In compiled languages (like C and C++) source code gets translated directly into machine code by a compiler, which then gets directly executed by your computer at runtime - in other words, your computer does *exactly* what the source code says. If you write the bad C program:

```
int main(){
    char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(char));
    ptr = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Then your computer will dutifully allocate a `char` shaped block of memory, storing its location in `ptr`, which then gets forgotten. A garbage-collected environment will see that in the line `ptr = NULL`, the memory that got allocated is now inaccessible, so it frees up the allocated memory for other programs to use, but compiling this in C will leave that memory allocated until the program exits.

Boehm-Demers-Weiser garbage collection is actually just a whole bunch more C code, hidden in the module, that replaces the underlying, dangerous `malloc` function with its own, safe, GC_MALLOC function that keeps track of loose pointers so you don't have to.

Python is not like C. Lines of code are interpreted by another program (usually written in C), which then tells the computer to do what you what you want it to do. The underlying code (memory addresses, pointer allocation and array management) is entirely hidden in Python. It is impossible to write a Python program that will do the same thing that `malloc` does in C.

In short: **No, you cannot tell Python to garbage collect C, because the Python interpreter already uses C programs that do garbage collection.**